# how to get the user info python-ldap

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-ldap

```
>>>conn=ldap.initialize('ldap://x.x.x.x')
>>>conn.simple_bind_s(uname+"@domain.com",pwd)
```

here am getting as

```
(97, [], 1, [])
```

but when i try to get the user details by

```
>>>conn.whoami_s()
```

am getting error saying

```
ldap.PROTOCOL_ERROR: {'info': '0000203D: LdapErr: DSID-0C090C7D, comment: Unknown extended request OID, data 0, vece', 'desc': 'Protocol error'}
```

can anyone please tell me how to retrieve the user details of the specified username and password??

please help am a newbie

Answer (score 0):

That error means the request is unknown, possibly because your Active Directory server is too old.

Per http://blog.dzhuvinov.com/?p=352, Active Directory only supported the whoami exop as of Windows 2008, and I think you have to sign in with the username as DOMAIN/user for it to work (possibly also need SASL/SSL).